# Logout implementation via CMIS standard

Tags: java, cmis

Could you tell me which method should I implement in order to logout. I want to do some staff on the server when user click button logout. I can't find such method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMIS doesn't cover authentication at all, neither in the [AtomPub](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/cmis-spec-v1.0-errata-01-os-complete.html#_Toc243905491) nor in the [WS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/cmis-spec-v1.0-errata-01-os-complete.html#_Toc243905609) bindings, relying on transport level security for authentication. AtomPub binding should leverage HTTP authentication, WS repositories should implement WS-Security 1.1.